# Create HibernateJpaVendorAdapter instance failed. Why?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I created a spring JPA example according to "Spring in Action", chapter 11.

Java config code:

```
@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    System.out.println(adapter);
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(true);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    return  adapter;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
    //emfb.setPersistenceUnitName("test");
    emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.springinaction.test");
    EntityManagerFactory emf = emfb.getObject();
    System.out.println(emf);
    return emf;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    //System.out.println(emf);
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Maven dependencies associated with Spring JPA:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The program runs fine up to this line of code:

```
System.out.println("hello");
HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
```

and fails with below error message:

```
hello
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class com.springinaction.test.JdbcConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter com.springinaction.test.JdbcConfig.jpaVendorAdapter()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
```

Someone said to me that the reason could be the absence of hibernate-entitymanger.jar, but I find this jar in local Maven repository.

And someone says that reason is missing ejb3-persistence.jar, but I couldn't find the Maven groupId/artifactId for this.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence is part of hibernate-entitymanager jar. Please check if this jar is in your project class path or in deployed war file. Also check the version of this jar file.Instead of providing hibernate-core and hibernate-jpa you should provide hibernate-entitymanager dependency in pom.xml and this will download all the required dependencies. You can check the same at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.2.2.Final

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The source code for Spring In Action is at https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/9/ef4e0ef-b7bd-4ab8-857d-eb635d18d425/SpringiA4_SourceCode.zip. You can check the build.gradle file for dependency used.